# How do we integrate the $\int \frac{1}{a\sin 2x+b\sin x}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to  integrate 
$$\int \frac{1}{a\sin 2x+b\sin x}dx$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants. I have tried converting the sin and cosine in terms of tangent but it leads nowhere.

Comment: probably do sin(2x) =2sin(x)cos(x) and then do u=tan(x/2) substitution

Comment: $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ then Weierstrass and it should come out then. I know it can be done for $a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)$ so this should also be not too bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:*
$$
\frac{1}{a\sin 2x+b\sin x} = \frac{\sin x}{(1-\cos^2 x)(2a\cos x+b)}
$$